# Узнать код купона в Битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс

Как узнать код купона, который был применен к товару? Я получаю текущую корзину, но там поле `DISCOUNT_COUPON=>null`, хотя сам купон применяется.

```
$dbBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
        array(
                "NAME" => "ASC",
                "ID" => "ASC"
            ),
        array(
                "FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(),
                "LID" => SITE_ID,
                "ORDER_ID" => "NULL"
            ),
        false,
        false,
        array("ID", "DISCOUNT_COUPON")
    );
while ($arItems = $dbBasketItems->Fetch())
{
        $arBasketItems[] = $arItems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если мыслить логически, то на момент существования корзины код купона еще не может быть применен. Купоны применяются в момент формирования заказа. ПОсле формирования заказа корзина уничтожается. Т.е. это как бы взаимоисключающие понятия. Код купона может висеть где-то в сессии. Рекомендую посмотреть экшен создания заказа. Там обязательно будет метод получения данных купона.

Comment: в тегах - Битрикс

Comment: Написано, что cms битрикс, код купона вводится на странице корзины, он там применяется и уже после этого происходит формирование заказа (город, платёжная система и тд), вот мне нужно на той получать еще и номер купона.

Comment: Купон еще не применен. На этапе корзины просто происходит пересчет стоимости согласно введенному купону. Если Вы найдете и посмотрите экшен корзины или заказа, то увидите там место, где происходит пересчет сумм согласно купону. Там же можно будет получить пример кода получения этого самого купона.

Comment: Получается что при нажатии на кнопку "Пересчитать"  заносит данные из поля ввода купона в переменную `$arResult["COUPON"]` Но эта переменная видна только на странице корзины. Мне нужно вытащить её на страницу оформления заказа.

Comment: Оно же как-то присваивает $arResult["COUPON"] нужное значение. Смотрим там как присваивается, копируем себе. Должно работать.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что у товаров в корзине есть свойство `["COUPON"]` , значит можно извлечь его значение, а у товар в оформлении заказа уже пересылается без этого свойства

Comment: Массив товара где-то подготавливается. Предлагаю найти это место.